# Change operator precedence for ∘

Tags: julia

I'd like to change the priority of `∘` so that it is applied first. Hence no bracket is needed in the function composition below. Is this possible?

```
julia> ∘(f,g) = x->f(g(x))              
∘ (generic function with 1 method)      

julia> (sqrt ∘ abs)(randn())            
0.9069709279812338  

julia> sqrt ∘ abs(randn())              
(::#15) (generic function with 1 method)
```

Comment: This `∘(f,g) = x->f(g(x)))` is already defined in Base.

Comment: It is technically possible to change priority in Julia source code (`src/julia-parser.scm` file I think), but, of course, this isn't recommended or portable. So, I would say, the short (and recommended) answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julia is strong at metaprogramming so you have to be able to make your own microlanguage.

I am just beginner at Julia so code below is just my little experiment! (And it is inclomplete because problems with parsing multiple lines )

But maybe it could be inspirational:

```bash
module M
  macro x(a)
    w = r"(\w+)\s*∘\s*(\w+)"  # trying to find words around ∘
    s = s"(\1 ∘ \2)"          # and enclosed them into brackets
    b = replace("$a", w, s)
    return :(eval(parse($b)))
  end
end

import M

M.@x(
  sqrt ∘ abs(randn())
)
```

Comment: Instead of parse it is better to use parseall from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46366560/1782955 and istead of `M.@x(
  sqrt ∘ abs(randn())
)` better to use `M.@x begin
  sqrt ∘ abs(randn())
end`. It allow to "translate" multiline, multiexpression blocks.