# Can I use <- instead of = in Julia?

Tags: julia

Like in R:

```
a <- 2
```

or even better

```
a ← 2
```

which should translate to

```
a = 2
```

and if possible respect method overloading.

Comment: https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/variables/#Variables-1

Comment: am I missing something? `const ← = =` does not work.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the docs...you need to use the `=` operator in order to assigna value to a variable in julia lang..

Comment: that was the question, whether it is possible to map something else to mean `=`. Since for example, one can do `const ← = +` and it works as expected.

Comment: Hmmm, one can overload many operators like `+, -` and even `≡`. They are in Base, i.e. e.g. `Base.:+` or `Base.:-`, but there is no `Base.:=`. It seems that `=` is not a function, try e.g. `@which a = 3`.

Comment: That's right, `=` is not an operator in Julia, and cannot be overloaded.

Comment: It is an operator it’s just a very special one. You’ve gotten spoiled by operators just being names with infix function call syntax – to the point where `=` is too magical to qualify. Of course in other languages most operators are magical – to the point where magic is almost part of the definition :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=` is overloaded (not in the multiple dispatch sense) a lot in Julia.

1. It binds a new variable. As in `a = 3`. You won't be able to use `←` instead of `=` in this context, because you can't overload binding in Julia.
2. It gets lowered to `setindex!`. As in, `a[i] = b` gets lowered to `setindex!(a, b, i)`. Unfortunately, `setindex!` takes 3 variables while `←` can only take 2 variables. So you can't overload `=` with 3 variables.

   But, you can use only 2 variables and overload `a[:] = b`, for example. So, you can define `←(a,b) =  (a[:] = b)` or `←(a,b) = setindex!(a,b,:)`.
3. `a .= b` gets lowered to `(Base.broadcast!)(Base.identity, a, b)`. You can overload this by defining `←(a,b) = (a .= b)` or `←(a,b) = (Base.broadcast!)(Base.identity, a, b)`.

So, there are two potentially nice ways of using `←`. Good luck ;)

Btw, if you really want to use `←` to do binding (like in 1.), the only way to do it is using macros. But then, you will have to write a macro in front of every single assignment, which doesn't look very good.

Also, if you want to explore how operators get lowered in Julia, do `f(a,b) = (a .= b)`, for example, and then `@code_lowered f(x,y)`.

Comment: "because you can't overload binding in Julia." Is there a technical reason why this is the case? or is it simply because they never implemented it?

Comment: Variable binding is a very basic operation in a language. When you define any function `f(a,b) = ... etc...` in Julia, it is impossible to assign a value to a like you could with `a = ..etc..`. So you would have to change the language itself if you want to have your own character that does variable binding. Probably the reason that two characters weren't implemented for variable binding is that it's redundant and it might confuse people reading the code.

Comment: There was also some discussion of this on https://discourse.julialang.org/t/is-it-possible-to-use-for-assignment/2973/7

Answer (score 5):

No. `=` is not an operator in Julia, and cannot be assigned to another symbol.

Comment: Hopefully the other answers are enlightening but this the only one I can really endorse as not enabling bad things. Trying to use a different syntax for `=` is really swimming against the current and will only lead to pain and suffering.

Comment: I mean, I can already do `const - = +` and confuse everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: You are fully responsible if you will try my (still beginner's) experiments bellow! :P

MacroHelper is module ( big thanks to @Alexander_Morley and @DanGetz for [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364922/how-to-parse-multiline-string-in-julia/46366560#46366560) ) I plan to play with in future and we could probably try it here :

```
julia> module MacroHelper
      # modified from the julia source ./test/parse.jl
      function parseall(str)
          pos = start(str)
          exs = []
          while !done(str, pos)
              ex, pos = parse(str, pos) # returns next starting point as well as expr
              ex.head == :toplevel ? append!(exs, ex.args) : push!(exs, ex)
      end
      if length(exs) == 0
          throw(ParseError("end of input"))
      elseif length(exs) == 1
           return exs[1]
      else
          return Expr(:block, exs...) # convert the array of expressions
                                      # back to a single expression
      end
   end
   end;
```

With module above you could define simple test "language":

```
julia> module TstLang
    export @tst_cmd
    import MacroHelper
    macro tst_cmd(a)
        b = replace("$a", "←", "=")  # just simply replacing ←
                                     # in real life you would probably like 
                                     # to escape comments, strings etc
        return MacroHelper.parseall(b)
    end
    end;
```

And by using it you could probably get what you want:

````
julia> using TstLang

julia> tst```
       a ← 3
       println(a)
       a +← a + 3 # maybe not wanted? :P 
       ```
3
9
````

What about performance?

````
julia> function test1()
         a = 3
         a += a + 3 
       end;

julia> function test2()
         tst```
           a ← 3
           a +← a + 3 
         ```
       end;

julia> test1(); @time test1();
  0.000002 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)

julia> test2(); @time test2();
  0.000002 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
````

If you like to see syntax highlight (for example in atom editor) then you need to use it differently:

```
function test3()
     @tst_cmd begin
        a ← 3
        a ← a + a + 3  # parser don't allow you to use "+←" here! 
     end
end;
```

We could hope that future Julia IDEs could syntax highlight cmd macros too. :)

What could be problem with "solution" above? I am not so experienced julian so many things. :P (in this moment something about "macro hygiene" and "global scope" comes to mind...)

But what you want is IMHO good for some [domain specific languages](https://julialang.org/blog/2017/08/dsl) and not to redefine basic of language! It is because readability very counts and if everybody will redefine everything then it will end in Tower of Babel...

Comment: Note that if you want to write a macro, you should *not* convert the ast to a string and then parse it — rather you can manipulate the ast directly. See [MacroTools.jl](https://github.com/FluxML/MacroTools.jl) for example